# Is there a performance implication of calling multiple objects in a row?

Tags: java, performance

Call A:

```
double Value = Object.Object.Object.Object.DoubleValue;
```

Call B:

```
double Value : Object.DoubleValue;
```

If this were in a for loop and being called many times over and over would there be a performance loss for calling an object within an object or is it worth noting about?

Comment: Let the compiler and jit optimize what it can for you, if you suspect something - use profiling and see if it is really an issue. This issue is premature optimization by definition.

Comment: Do you have a link on how the compiler works, I'd like to know exactly what it's doing :-)

Comment: You have the bytecode, just look at it.

Comment: @user1134192: This is a HUGE field in CS called *theory of compilation*. There are a lot of optimizations taking place behind the scenes by the compiler and the jit optimization of your jvm. To understand more about compilers I suggest [The Dragon Book](http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Readbility is for programmers, optimizations are for compilers (and jit optimizations, to be honest).

**Do whatever is the standard in your team and is more readable**.

If after you do it you suspect some performance issue - use a profiler to check if it is indeed the case, and do adjustments accordingly.

Comment: +1 I should have pointed out that have clear, simple code is almost always more important than performance unless you *know* it is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

> is it not worth noting about?

Its could cost you tens of nano-seconds (is that important to you?)  The JIT fairly good at optimising/caching reference look ups so placing them in local variable is unlikely to be mcuh faster. i.e. even if it matters there is unlikely to be something simple you can do about it.

Comment: There is almost always a preformance impact of some kind and in almost all of these question it's too small to worry about. ;)